# Can you put a xsl:if test inside a Choose statement in an xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have to build a small conditional statement and I am not sure of the best approach.  I also am unsure if you can put an IF test inside of a Choose/When Statement. (I'm assuming you cannot??)

Trying to resolve the following condition:
Map "custom_field" from one system to "Position" in a separate system: if custom field happens to be blank, then default to the value being passed in the same named field "Position" from system A to "Position" in system B.

"Position" comes over by default and should never be blank in the xml- but the custom field has the potential to be blank.  Preference is that the custom field will be used, but if it is blank the default data should kick in.

```
<user>
<Custom_Field>Data</Custom_Field>
<Position>Data</Position>
</user>
```

Is this legal:

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:if test="custom_field != ''">
      <Position><xsl:value-of select='.'/></Position>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:choose>
```

Or does a Choose statement only work with When?
How can I evaluate whether or not the custom field is blank and setup a default scenario if it is blank?

Sorry- its a sink or swim environment and I'm still learning.  All help is greatly appreciated and noted for future reference.

Possible Scenarios I am trying to achieve based on data in XML:

Scenario 1:
Input XML:

```
<user>
<Custom_Field>Admin</Custom_Field>
<Position>Teacher</Position>
</user>
```

Output XML:

```
<user>
   <Position>Admin</Position>
</user>
```

Scenario 2:
Input XML:

```
<user>
<Custom_Field></Custom_Field>
<Position>Teacher</Position>
</user>
```

Output XML:

```
<user>
   <Position>Teacher</Position>
</user>
```

Comment: I potentially could I suppose but I wasn't sure how I could reference the field possibly being blank.  I can give that a try.

Comment: When I attempt to set it up using a Choose/When there isn't a way that I know of to then say Position should equal Position.  Because my when test is based on a different field completely.  Am I incorrect?

Comment: Ok in psuedocode this is what I want to achieve:

xsl:if test custom field != blank'
'Then position = custom field'
'/xsl:if'

'xsl:if test custom field = blank'
'Then position = position'
'xsl:if'

I will also edit my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `xsl:choose` you can use only `xsl:when` or `xsl:otherwise`. In pseudo code `xsl:choose` can be written as

```
if (condition 1)
...
else if (condition 2)
...
else if (condition 3)
...
else
...
```

where `if` and `else if` are `xsl:when` and `else` is `xsl:otherwise`.

`xsl:if` it is just a single condition:

```
if (condition)
...
```

**Update**:

Input:

```
<user>
  <Custom_Field>Data1</Custom_Field>
  <Position>Data2</Position>
</user>
```

**XSLT**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/user">
    <Position>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Custom_Field != ''">
          <xsl:value-of select='Custom_Field'/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select='Position'/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </Position>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for confirming that.  So do I need to make 2 conditional statements in order to achieve the end result?

Comment: That does it! My initial statement was incorrect and I was attempting to evaluate it much more difficult than was necessary.

Comment: Apologies- I neglected to say Thank you! I was excited. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

I would add another point to the answer: XSLT beginners often make excessive use of xsl:choose. You haven't shown enough code to see if that's the case here. But very often, the right way to do conditional processing in XSLT is by breaking up your template rules into smaller rules, and putting predicates in the match patterns, for example

```
<xsl:template match="para[@class='x']>...

<xsl:template match="para[@class='y']>...
```